# Writing validations rules using an XML vocabulary

Tags: xml, xsd

can somebody give me an example of how to write rules using custom tag in xml, the requirement is i need to write the rules in xml (eg :rule 1:  in a purchase order , if the customer ships to many different addresses, then it is a fradulent transaction).

once the rules are written in xml then output this to a xslt (which is next part of the task)

thanks for any help

Comment: I understood nothing from what you said.

Answer (score 2):

### [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/)

Sounds like exactly what you need.  The Schematron files are XML and can be compiled into XSLT.  You can use it to validate all sorts of custom business rules and logic.

[image: Schematron]

> The Schematron differs in basic
>   concept from other schema languages in
>   that it not based on grammars but on
>   finding tree patterns in the parsed
>   document. This approach allows many
>   kinds of structures to be represented
>   which are inconvenient and difficult
>   in grammar-based schema languages. If
>   you know XPath or the XSLT expression
>   language, you can start to use The
>   Schematron immediately.
>
> And it has free and open source
>   implementations available.
>
> The Schematron is trivially simple to
>   implement on top of XSLT and to
>   customize. (There are also
>   implementations in Python and Perl)
>
> The Schematron allows you to develop
>   and mix two kinds of schemas:
>
> 1.) ***Report*** elements allow you to diagnose
>   which variant of a language you are
>   dealing with.
>
> 2.) ***Assert*** elements allow
>   you to confirm that the document
>   conforms to a particular schema.
>
> The
>   Schematron is based on a simple
>   action:
>
> - First, find a context nodes in the
>     document (typically an element) based
>     on XPath path criteria;
> - Then, check to
>     see if some other XPath expressions
>     are true, for each of those nodes.

An example Schematron pattern:

```
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"  > 
  <sch:title>Test number of shipping addresses</sch:title>   
  <sch:p>This schema tests whether multiple shipping addresses have been used. </sch:p>
  <sch:ns prefix="po" uri="http://example.org/PurchaseOrder" />     
  <sch:pattern  id="P1"> 
    <sch:rule context="po:order">
    <sch:report test="po:address[2]"
        >Multiple shipping addresses are not allowed</sch:report>
     </sch:rule>       
  </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mads, it indeed is very helpful